# Reinstall/Reconfigure GUI Ubuntu 2015.04

Tags: asus, nvidia

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for my workstation and had issues with chromes hardware accelleration so i tried to install the matching nvidia drivers. I used the nvidia installer to install the drivers on my ASUS k55vd. It said i had a GeForce 610m on it, downloaded the right drivers and followed the instructions.

Upon reboot, my GUI doesn't load anymore, it flashes and return to lightdm login.

I tried following instructions on the net to reconfigure xserver-xorg but it always tells me that i don't have that package installed.

I tried running the nvidia installer with --uninstall to no avail, still does the same thing.

Notes about the steps that occured while installing:

- ModProbe config was changed so that "Nouveau" kernel module gets disabled
- X config was changed and supposedly backed up but i can't find anything in terms of config or backup in /etc/x11

Answer (score 1):

Finaly found it after 30min or so of more browsing. What i had to reinstall was the ubuntu desktop using:

- sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-desktop
- sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
- sudo service lightdm restart
- Switch back to display (ctrl + alt + f7) or reboot (sudo reboot)